# Can you Resize image BLOB objects delivered via an Oracle Data View?

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, image-resizing

Presently we're delivering some imaging information to different populations at their default size but I have an group of end-users looking to receive imaging data that we have stored in BLOBs in a specific file size that doesn't match the  current file size.

What I'm wonder is if there a way to construct a data view that automatically resizes the image BLOBs on delivery?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has the [`ORDImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28414/ch_imgref.htm#BABFHIHG) data type for images. It allows you to get the size and some metadata, but I don't think it allows you to resize the image. You need an image manipulation library, and I don't know of a PL/SQL one.